# AJAX PHP JavaScript code not running on Iphone or Ipad

Tags: javascript, php, ios, ajax

I have javascript file which uses some AJAX post requests, basically the file is linked to a submit button on a form on my site, when the form is submitted it then takes the form data and uses the inputs to edit a svg file using xml then saves it to the server as a png and then sends it with an email to the user.

My problem is that it works perfect on windows desktop and on andriod (kindle) but when i try to use it on iphone or ipad it executes the ajax php post requests for making the image (piechart.php) and mailing it (mail.php) but doesnt execute the code to save the file to the server (upload.php), which means all the emails are being sent without the image.

I ran MIH Tool on my Iphone and it came back with no errors but this is where i found that the upload.php wasnt being executed

Here is the js file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.resetForm', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     /* Act on the event */
        location.reload();
    });

function base64ToBlob(base64, mime) 
{
    mime = mime || '';
    var sliceSize = 1024;
    var byteChars = window.atob(base64);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0, len = byteChars.length; offset < len; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteChars.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: mime});
}


// FUNCTION MAKING CANVAS WITH SVG
function drawInlineSVG(ctx, rawSVG, callback) 
{
    var svg = new Blob([rawSVG], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),
                domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
                url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),
                img = new Image;
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0); 
        domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        callback(this);
    };
    img.src = url;
}


//****************************************
function jim(){

    var svgText = document.getElementById("myViewer").outerHTML;
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctxt = myCanvas.getContext("2d");


    // FUNCTION TO SET ENCODED SVG TEXT IN INPUT
    drawInlineSVG(ctxt, svgText, function() {
        //lamba url
        shorternUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        shorternUrl = shorternUrl.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

        var blob = base64ToBlob(shorternUrl, 'image/png');
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('encodeURL', blob);
        $.ajax({
                url:"upload.php",
                type: "POST", 
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData})
        .done(function(e){
            $(".successMessageWrap").html('<div class="successMessageWrapTable"><div class="successMessage"><a class="resetForm" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a><img src="images/logo.png"><h2>Thanks for using <span>Wheel of Life</span></h2><p>A copy of your wheel of life has been sent into your Email Id</p><a href="index.php" onclick="reloadPage();">Make New</a></div></div>');
        });


/*success: function(data)
{

$(".successMessageWrap").html('<div class="successMessageWrapTable"><div class="successMessage"><a class="resetForm" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a><img src="images/logo.png"><h2>Thanks for using <span>Wheel of Life</span></h2><p>A copy of your wheel of life has been sent into your Email Id</p><a href="index.php" onclick="reloadPage();">Make New</a></div></div>');

}*/





});
}
//***************************

$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

//

if(check_radio('PhysicalRank','Physical Environment')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('EnyInput','Physical Environment')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('BussinessRank','Business/Career')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('BussinessInput','Business/Career')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('financeRank','Finances')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('FinanceInput','Finances')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('HealthRank','Health')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('HealthInput','Health')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('FFRank','Family & Friends')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('FFInput','Family & Friends')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('RelationRank','Romance/ Relationships')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('RelationInput','Romance/ Relationships')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('GrowthRank','Personal Growth')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('GrothInput','Personal Growth')==false){return false;}

if(check_radio('FunRank','Fun & Recreation')==false){return false; }
if(check_input('FunInput','Fun & Recreation')==false){return false;}



if(check_input('name','Name')==false){return false;}
if(check_input('email','Email')==false){return false;}



//diable submit
$("input#WheelSubmit").attr('type', '');
$("input#WheelSubmit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');



$(".successMessageWrap").fadeIn();


//AJAX
$.ajax({
url:"piechart.php",
type:"POST",
data:new FormData(this),
contentType: false,
processData:false,
cache:false,
success: function(data)
{

$(".piechartSvg").html(data);


jim();



}
});

//*************************



//AJAX
$.ajax({
url:"mail.php",
type:"POST",
data:new FormData(this),
contentType: false,
processData:false,
cache:false,
success: function(data)
{


$("#test").html(data);

}
});



});




});//main
```

I have been working it this for days and cant understand why it is only that part that isn't executing on iOs devices even using chrome on iphone doesn't work either

If anyone could help that would be great thanks

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous, so it's perfectly possible `upload.php` *is* running - your problem being that it's just running *after* `mail.php` is executed.

Comment: But it runs fine on desktop and I know the upload.php doesn't run because I used mih tool on iPhone and checked the network tab and it wasn't being accessed and the done function wasn't executing either so the successwrap wasn't changing on the site